# Как в с# из разных форм обратиться к одному массиву?

Tags: c#, массивы, winforms

Есть проект Windows Forms. В нем создано несколько форм. Как можно обратиться к массиву `List<AUD> mas = new List<AUD>();` из каждой формы?!

Comment: А как обычно вы из нескольких классов получаете доступ к одним и тем же данным? Ну вот, тут точно так же.

Comment: Объявите его как `public static` и обращайтесь к нему, откуда вздумается.

Comment: @stribizhev: Вот так прямо вне зависимости от семантики?

Comment: @VladD: Я не даю правильный ответ, а намекаю. Ясное дело, что просто `mas` не напишешь из любой формы.

Comment: @stribizhev: Не, я не отвечаю на учебные вопросы, если только они не являются _очень_ интересными. В любом случае, правильный ответ очень зависит от семантики. Может, это публичное свойство первой формы, а может, глобальная настройка, а может, свойство текущей операции в бизнес-логике, а может, и единственный по своей природе объект.

Answer (score 2):

Форма  - это просто особый класс, в котором определены методы отображения на экране. Для того чтобы несколько форм могли взаимодействовать с общими данными можно сделать следующее:

1. Передавать объект как параментр конструктору при создании дополнительной формы (или завести метод SetData() для передачи форме данных) `MyForm mf = new MyForm(List<AUD> mas)`; соответсвенно надо будет изменить конструкор формы.
2. Можно объявить список как открытое статическое поле (лучше свойство) внутри какой-либо, тогда обращаться к нему можно `MyForm.list` (этот вариант не рекомендую)
3. Можно вынести список в дополнительный класс данных, где объявить его аналогично предыдущему пункту. (уже лучше)
4. Еще вариант: передавать делегат, который будет возвращать список, возможно проводя с ним определенную работу.

Лично я больше склоняюсь к первому варианту.

Comment: @Erlich, если ответ вам помог, отметьте его как лучший (галочка рядом с ответом).

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).